# Removing "Installed Updates" Entries for Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10

With the release of Visual Studio 2015 yesterday, I have upgraded to the 2015 version and uninstalled Visual Studio 2013. Despite this, I seem to still have entries for Visual Studio 2013 in my list of Installed Updates.

[image: Visual Studio 2013 listed in Installed Updates]

I have tried removing the updates, but what ends up happening is the updates start reinstalling since they have apparently been uninstalled, and eventually fail. How can I remove all entries for Visual Studio 2013 from my list of installed updates? I am running Windows 10 Pro x64 Build 10240.

Comment: Since the data is no longer there, you can use any number of tools, to remove the entry themselfs.  You can also reinstall VS2013 and those updates, then remove the updates then VS2013.

Comment: I would much prefer the first of the two options. What could I use to remove the entry? I assume this information is stored somewhere in the registry, but I do not know where myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove these two update entries from my list of Installed Updates, I used the registry editor to search for the KB numbers of the updates, in this case, `KB2829760` and `KB2932965` and deleted all keys pertaining to them. This removed the entries for the updates.